# OpenGL mesh/meshpart line thickness

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

In LibGDX 2d we can draw/define line thickness with "lineWidth" e.g.

```
shapeRenderer.rectLine(new Vector2(x1,y1),new Vector2(x2,y2),lineWidth);
```

Is there a way to implement something similar in Mesh or meshpart without changing glLineWidth() value?

Thanks.

Comment: No. The 2D lines are achieved by drawing filled rectangles. You can write a Shader implementation that switches the GL code back and forth. Not all Android devices support line widths greater than 1.

Comment: Thank you 10-4, could you post it, so I can accept